# How can I accomplish this effect?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have been struggling for days, I have tried a lot of things but I can't get it to work.

This is the effect:

[image: Slide over another view]

(Slide / scroll over another fixed view on top).

Comment: I have tried many things and the closest I have been is a `ScrollView` scrolling **below** a fixed view on top (using `layout_below`).

Comment: [here is it](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Comment: I've came accross that library, but I think if you know how to accomplish that effect is not necessary to use a lib. I don't think it's hard to make it work, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can try with Bottom Sheets Android

Comment: @DeepakGoyal I don't think that's the way to do it, but thanks anyway.

Comment: i was just writing it. that's the solution @DeepakGoyal

Comment: Did you try coordinator layout?

Comment: @Grender it's nativa and suggested from google so I think this is the correct way

Comment: @MohammedAtif Yes, I have tried it.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley It's not the same effect as I'm posting here. (You wan view it better if you install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wallapop and go to some user's profile.

Comment: @Grender At the moment I can't but I really think the one they are using is a custom implementation of the bottom sheet. not sure 100% but they look really the same, you just have to customize the fab and the view :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CoordinatorLayout, set MapView instead of the default ImageView, and put the rest of layout inside NestedScrollView.

Comment: I have tried that too, but with not succesful effects, would you mind giving me a working example?

Comment: I'm on mobile, so I posted it on pastebin. Not tested, but it should work, just check for errors

Comment: What if I want to implement it in a `Fragment`? Will it work removing the `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`?

Comment: Yes, it should :-)